# Grouping top N rows, but also needing to sum column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to group the top N rows in my data set:

```
SELECT mgap_ska_id,mgap_ska_id_name, account_manager_id, 
mgap_growth AS growth,mgap_recovery,
(mgap_growth+mgap_recovery) total
  FROM
  (SELECT mgap_ska_id,mgap_ska_id_name, account_manager_id, mgap_growth,
  mgap_recovery,(mgap_growth+mgap_recovery) total,
    @acid_rank := IF(@current_acid = account_manager_id, @acid_rank + 1, 1) 
    AS acid_rank,
       @current_acid := account_manager_id 
       FROM mgap_orders
       ORDER BY account_manager_id, mgap_growth DESC 
     ) ranked
     WHERE acid_rank <= 5
```

and the result is VERY close to what I need, but I am having an aggregate issue that I need help with. I have attcached a screenshot of my query results (I had to block out the customer names and ids for privacy; the mgap_ska_id and account_manager_id are INT columns and the mgap_ska_id_name is a VARCHAR.

[image]

In theory I need to SUM (I know its an aggregate; that is the issue) multiple mgap_growth values while keeping the ranking in tact.

If I GROUP BY, then I lose the top 5 ranking. Currently, the mgap_growth value is only one value per mgap_ska_id within the mgap_growth column; I need it to be the SUM of all mgap_growth values per mgap_ska_id and keep the top five ranking as shown.

Thanks!

Comment: If `account_manager_id` is autogenerated, it doesn't really tell us anything related to privacy.  What do you want the results to actually look like?  It would help to have sample starting data (properly anonymized) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line in your select fields:

```
(SELECT SUM(t.mgap_growth) FROM mgap_orders t WHERE t.mgap_ska_id = ranked.mgap_ska_id ) AS total_mgap_growth
```

So your code will be:

```
SELECT mgap_ska_id,mgap_ska_id_name, account_manager_id, 
mgap_growth AS growth,mgap_recovery,
(mgap_growth+mgap_recovery) total,
(SELECT SUM(t.mgap_growth) FROM mgap_orders t WHERE t.mgap_ska_id = ranked.mgap_ska_id ) AS total_mgap_growth
  FROM
  (SELECT mgap_ska_id,mgap_ska_id_name, account_manager_id, mgap_growth,
  mgap_recovery,(mgap_growth+mgap_recovery) total,
    @acid_rank := IF(@current_acid = account_manager_id, @acid_rank + 1, 1) 
    AS acid_rank,
       @current_acid := account_manager_id 
       FROM mgap_orders
       ORDER BY account_manager_id, mgap_growth DESC 
     ) ranked
     WHERE acid_rank <= 5
```